# Is passing empty strings ("") in C bad practice?

Tags: c

I'm trying to fix a bug in very old C code that just popped up recently on Windows after we updated Visual Studio to version 2017. The code still runs on several linux platforms. That tells me we're probably relying on some undefined behavior, and we previously got lucky.

We have a bunch of function calls like this:

get_some_data(parent, "ge", "", type);

Running in debug, I noticed that upon entry to this function, that empty string is immediately filled with garbage, **before the function has done anything**. The function is declared like this:

```
static void get_some_data(
KEY  Parent,
char *Prefix,
char *Suffix,
ENT  EntType)
```

So is it unwise to pass the strings directly ("ge", "")? I know it's trivial to fix this case by declaring char *suffix="" and passing suffix instead of "", but I'm now questioning whether I need to go through this entire suite of code looking for this type of function call.

Comment: You usually pass `NULL` when the argument is not needed, not `""`. That's not common practice at all and pretty strange. If you want to get any relevant answer you need to post the actual code. We cannot tell you what to fix if there is no code to fix.

Comment: `Is passing empty strings (“”) in C bad practice?` No.

Comment: If you are passing literal strings and trying to modify them in the subroutine, that would be a problem.

Comment: As long you don't attempt to modify the string you pass in (empty or not) it's not a problem.  If you've got UB going on, you need to run the code through a memory analyzer.  If it compiles on Linux, you can use valgrind for this.  Not familiar with Windows equivalents.

Comment: You are gonna read to read the documentation for that function. Or if it was written by some amateur who didn't document it, dig through the code to see what it does.

Comment: If defining `char *suffix = ""` and passing suffix instead of `""` fixes the problem, then it hasn't fixed the problem.  It's (probably) just made it go to a different form of UB.

Comment: It depends entirely on the function called. Its behavior shall be documented, and if you are trying to use it without knowing what is supposed to be passed as argument, problems will certainly happen. It seems you are trying to guess. The C language allows passing an empty string, and allows passing a NULL. But for this specific function, nobody can guess, not even you.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I put the function declaration in my original post - I know what it does. It expects to receive a char *. I'm just asking if passing "" is bad practice.

Comment: You don't understand. I don't care about the declaration, but about what the function actually does. Silly example: if you are supposed to pass a string that will be overwritten with a fixed amount of data and you pass an empty string, you will have a buffer overflow. Maybe a NULL will be understood as "don't write anything", but it could also end up with a null pointer exception. What is your function supposed to do with an empty string or with a NULL?

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you expand on this? It's my understanding that when I define `char *suffix=""`, suffix now contains `'\0'`. Does passing `""` also insert a null terminator into the argument of the called function?

Comment: There will be a null terminator in the string argument, but it comes from the string being... a string. Passing a NULL pointer and passing an empty string (effectively a pointer to a zero byte) are not the same thing.

Comment: Yes, whether you pass `""` or a variable that is initialized to `""`, it will be the same.  But often UB changes with small things like introducing new variables.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what the function actually does is trivial. It does NOT try to write anything to these char * arguments. I'm not that dumb. :) I'm also not free to paste my company's code here, and anyway it's long and convoluted. My point is, **immediately** once I'm inside the called function I can see these strings that were passed as "" are now filled with garbage.

Comment: Ok. But something is writing this garbage. Maybe a bug somewhere that ends up overwriting a string while it shouldn't (could be a kind of buffer overflow).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm afraid that must be the case.

Comment: Also, you write that immediately after entering the function, the strings are filled with garbage. But what was the content immediately *before* entering the function? Maybe the garbage occurs long before entering the function? I have another concern: a string litteral can't be overwritten with garbage, normally (often it resides in a memory area that is read-only). How do you check for this garbage? A printf with the string?

Comment: A quick check on Windows, with a function that *does* overwrite its string argument: Visual C++ (cl) produces an executable that happily overwrites a string litteral. The Intel C++ compiler (icl) does not, and does actually nothing (not even crash). They both overwrite a char array passed as argument, as expected.

Comment: Interesting difference between VS and Intel. I don't know how to check the string contents before entering the function - the function is *called* with the argument `""`, and the next step (inside the called function) that argument is garbage.

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question about this behaviour. Make sure you mention all the necessary details. Ideally, [mcve], but I doubt you can make your code minimal and still reproduce the problem. You should at least try, and describe what you tried and what the result was. Also, do some disassembly of the function call. Some ideas to check and describe: is there a mismatch in function declarations (prototypes) or calling conventions? Does the problem happen if you make a new function with same functionality? Try reordering the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it unwise to pass the strings directly ("ge", "")?

There is nothing inherently wrong with passing string literals to functions in general.

However, it is unwise to pass pointers (in)to string literals specifically to parameters declared as pointers to non-`const` char, because C specifies that undefined behavior results from attempting to modify a string literal, and in practice, that UB often manifests as abrupt program termination.  If a function declares a parameter as `const char *` then you can reasonably take that as a promise that it will not attempt to modify the target of that pointer -- which is what you need to ensure -- but if it declares a parameter as just `char *` then no such promise is made, and the function doesn't even have a way to check at runtime whether the argument is writable.

Possibly you can rely on documentation in place of `const`-qualification, for you're ok in this regard as long as no attempt is made in practice to modify a string literal, but that still leaves you more open to bugs than you otherwise would be.

> I know it's trivial to fix this case by declaring char *suffix="" and passing suffix instead of ""

Such a change may disguise what you're doing from the compiler, so that it does not warn about the function call, but **it does not fix anything**.  The same pointer value is passed to the function either way, and the same semantics and constraints apply.  Also, if the compiler warned about the function call then it should also warn about the assignment.

This is not an issue in C++, by the way, or at least not the same issue, because in C++, string literals represent arrays of `const char` in the first place.

> , but I'm now questioning whether I need to go through this entire suite of code looking for this type of function call.

Better might be to modify the signatures of the called functions.  Where you intend for it to be ok to pass a string literal, ensure that the parameter has type `const char *`, like so:

```
static void get_some_data(
KEY  Parent,
const char *Prefix,
const char *Suffix,
ENT  EntType)
```

But do note that is highly likely to cause new warnings about violations of const-correctness.  To ensure safety, you need to fix these, too, *without casting away `const`ness*.  This could well cascade broadly, but the exercise will definitely help you identify and fix places where your code was mishandling string literals.

On the other hand, a genuine fix that might be less pervasive would be to pass pointers to modifiable arrays instead of (unmodifiable) string literals.  Perhaps that's what you had in mind with your proposed fix, but the correct way to do that is this:

```
char prefix[] = "ge";
char suffix[] = "";

get_some_data(parent, prefix, suffix, type);
```

Here, `prefix` and `suffix` are separate (modifiable) local arrays, initialized with copies of the string literals' contents.

---

With all that said, I'm inclined to suspect that if you're getting bona fide runtime errors related to these arguments with VS-compiled executables but not GCC-compiled ones, then the source of those is probably something else.  My first guess would be that array bounds are being overrun.  My second guess would be that you are compiling C code as C++, and running afoul of one or more of the (other) differences between them.

That's not to say that you shouldn't take a good look at the `const`ness / writability concerns involved here, but it would suck to go through the whole exercise just to find out that you were ok to begin with.  You could still end up with better code, but that's a little tricky to sell to the boss when they ask why the bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if adding `const` to the function's parameter declarations would cure it, but it's fascinating that the real bug may be hiding elsewhere (some array bound overrun or similar).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is absolutely nothing wrong with passing a string literal, empty or not. Quite the opposite — if you try to "fix" your code by doing your trivial change, you will hide the bug and make life harder for whoever is going to fix it in future.

Comment: Interesting. That leaves me stumped as to why that argument gets filled with garbage immediately upon entering the function. As @dbush commented, I guess I need to run it through a memory analyzer.

Comment: This answer seems a bit light to me.  There are indeed potential issues here that should not be ignored.

Comment: @JohnBollinger please elaborate. What potential issues?

Comment: Wait for my answer, @GDub.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem and the cause was a similar situation in a recently executed function where, crucially, the contents of the string were being changed.

Prior to the call where this strange behaviour was being observed, there was a call to older code with a parameter of PSTR type. Not realizing that the contents of that parameter were going to be changed, a programmer had supplied an empty string. The code was only ever updating the first character so declaring a char type parameter and supplying the address of that was sufficient to solve the problem that was exhibiting in the later call.